# Need to make Amazon S3 bucket public from API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, public, bucket

I've spent over a week on this issue, and Amazon does not provide any resources that can answer this for me. I have built a custom CMS that allows thousands of users to upload their own files. Those files need to be migrated to a CDN, as they are beginning to overwhelm the file system at near 50GB. I have already integrated with Amazon's S3 PHP SDK. My application must be able to do the following:

1. Create and remove buckets through the API, not the console. This is working.
2. Perform all CRUD operations on the files uploaded to the buckets, again explicitly through the console. Creating and removing files is working.
3. As part of CRUD, these files must then be readable via HTTP/HTTPS as they are required assets in the web application. These are all registering as 'Access Denied', due to the buckets not being public by default.

As I understand it, the point of a CDN is that Content can be Delivered via a Network. I need to understand how to make these files visible in a web application without the use of the console, as these buckets will be dynamically created by users and it's a game-breaker to require administration to update them manually.

I'd appreciate it if someone help me resolve this.

Comment: Welcome Daniel; do you keep track of which user is allowed to see/download which file ?or do you want all files in this buckets to be publicly available to everyone ?

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Amazon S3 are **private by default**. If you wish to make the objects **public** (meaning accessible to everyone in the world), there are two methods:

- When uploading the objects, mark them as `ACL=public-read`. This Access Control List will make the object itself public. *OR*
- Add a **bucket policy** to the bucket that will make the *entire bucket* (or, if desired, a portion of the bucket) public.

From [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Such a policy can be added after bucket creation by using [`putBucketPolicy()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putbucketpolicy).

Also, please be aware that **Amazon S3 Block Public Access** is turned on by default on buckets to prevent exposing private content. The above method will require this block to be turned off. This can be done programmatically with [`putPublicAccessBlock()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putpublicaccessblock) or [`deletePublicAccessBlock()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#deletepublicaccessblock).

Comment: I ended up going with the putObject -> ACL: 'public-read' property, which resolved it outright. Thanks everyone.